# Java: Marking/Flagging a file

Tags: java, file, flags, marker, file-conversion

I would like to know whether or not there is some way of marking a file to identify whether or not the file contains **x**.

*Consider the following example:*

During a batch conversion process I am creating a log file which lists the success / failure of individual conversions.

So the process is as follows:

- start conversion process
- create log file named batch_XXX_yyyy_mm_dd.log
- **try to convert 'a'**
- *write success to log file*
- **try to convert 'b'**
- *write success to log file*
- ...
- **try to convert 'z'**
- *write success to log file*
- close and persist log file

What I would like to be able to do is mark a file in some way that identifies whether any of the conversions logged in the file were unsuccessful.

I do not want to change the file name (visibly) and I do not want to open the file to check for a marker.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this could be achieved?

Comment: +1 for this question. I have googled this topic but couldn't find any good information. Tagging files is very useful. I could think of many different cases.

Comment: @Korinna Thanks. It would appear that in Java 7 we will be able to add attributes to files through [java.nio.file.Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getAttribute%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29)

Comment: I digged into this a little bit: weird. Do you know what SebiesnrMkudrfcoIaamtykdDa is?

Comment: @Korinna No, sorry. I had a quick google on it and it didn't bring up anything helpful. Ask on the [Super User](http://superuser.com/) Stack Exchange - they will probably know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add file attributes in [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) through the [java.nio.file.Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class.

So it would be possible to mark whether a file contains X using the [`Files.setAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setAttribute%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) method:

```
Files.setAttribute( "path/to/file", "containsX", true );
```

And then check whether the file does contain X using the [`Files.getAttribute( )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getAttribute%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) method:

```
Files.getAttribute( "path/to/file", "containsX" )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking into say

```
file.log
```

create another file which will maintain this info say

```
file.log.status
```

Your status file can then contain all the information you need. It will be easier to get the status of conversion for all the files as well as easy to map back to original file given a status file.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this seems like a list to monitor my lists. Ideally what I would like to do is get a file and check (without referencing anywhere else or opening it up) whether it contains a failed conversion.

Comment: If you need that information to be persistent, you need to store it somewhere and then read it back later, if not, then simply use a Map or something to keep that information in memory.

Comment: Well the information about whether something failed is persisted in the log file, but I was hoping that there might be a spare `bit` somewhere that I could turn on/off that would help me mark a file.

Comment: That would be too OS and File System specific and sure wont be portable with Java.

Comment: Thanks - that has given me something to think about